# How to generate an .EXE with different Name than the main Assembly?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, exe, .net-assembly

I have a WPF application with lot of XAML code referencing the main assembly (for widgets, styles and these things).

But now I need to change the name of the .EXE, but not its source main assembly for not updating so many dependencies.

How to do it as simple as possible?

Comment: Do you mean that you need to rename the .exe but don't want all of your XAML namespace references to break?

Answer (score 4):

Go to the project's properties and change "Assembly name" setting on the "Application" tab:

[image]

Comment: No! That changes the assembly name, therefore all the XAML dependencies must be updated. I need just to change the .EXE name.

Comment: It shouldn't affect it, if you don't change your namespace, I don't see why it would matter.

Comment: I want to avoid the manual change. Plus, a Setup project always take the main project output as the product source.

Comment: @Néstor - It is not possible to change the EXE name without changing the assembly name inside Visual Studio. So the only option you have is to change it manually or with a post build script.

Comment: This won't work, everything gets messed up if the assembly name is changed

Comment: I changed `Assembly Name` and everything is OK for me, no problems.
I have no idea why guys told that it could lead to "everything gets messed up".

Comment: It works, but the process still with the same name that was before. To fix completely I changed the Assembly Name as you sad and there's another button close to yours called Assembly Information. It opens a popup and you have to change the property Title.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the file name after the build? You could use a post-build script.

Answer (score 0):

You could put an xml namespace definition in your assembly.cs file (in properties folder). The in your XAML reference the code using the xml namespace defination instead of your namespace.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086.aspx